# How do rubber grid, which will be to work with fix margin?

Tags: html, css

I solve this task. And i wanna hear answers by other persons :)

**Task:**
Adaptive grid, max three colomn, which have rubber width and fixed margin of one another.

**Problem:**
If i set max width for anyone colomn, but i resize browser's window my colomn rebuilt in 2 colomn.

*example:*
parent's width: 990px
margin of colons: 12px
available width: 990 - 12*2 = 966px.

colomn's width: (966 / 3) / 990 ~ 32.5%

How do solve this problem?

I thought about breakpoint, but i think it is't good solution.

```css
* {
  
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  max-width: 990px;
  background: #000;
}

.posts {
    font-size: 0;
}

.main__wrapper {
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px 38px
}

.post {
  width: 32.45%; /* 914 - 12*2 = 890  */
  background: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.post:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="main__wrapper">
      <div class="posts">
        <div class="post"></div>
        <div class="post"></div>
        <div class="post"></div>
        <div class="post"></div>
        <div class="post"></div>
        <div class="post"></div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </main>  
</body>
```

I wanna, that 3 colomns don't rebuilt on 2 colomns. IE9+

Comment: From your question, it's unclear the exact layout you are looking for.

Comment: Use `flexbox`...drops mic! :)

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understand you want to make your table **responsive**.
There are really many (and very clear and simple to follow) tutorials on the internet. You can check this one: http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns

I think it really answers your question, and there is no need for me to copy/paste it, or say the same thing with just different words :)

Have a great day!